# Print backslash as a Code Sample

Tags: support

How to print backslash character as code sample in comments? `\`

Comment: How about this `\\`?

Comment: yes, i thought there's a way to format it as in the question

Comment: Chris meant to say this: `\`\\\``

Comment: Yeah - I was testing it out before posting an answer.

Comment: @Jongware, how did you type that?

Comment: I come up with ``\``

Comment: That's getting *meta* ... Let me think – I might not get it right first time: `\\\`\\\\\\\\\\``, resulting in `\`\\\\`` (ow forget it! and I got it right first time!!)

Answer (score 8):

Just use a double `\\`. To get the comment above I typed:

```
How about this `\\`?
```

Which comes out as:

> How about this `\`?

However to get a backslash in comment format you need to type this:

```
How about this ``\``?
```

which comes out as:

> How about this `\`?

Comment: Thanks Chris, but i wanted it this way.. ``\``